# What are @ in codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Since I'm new and just started to work on the Codeigniter framework I've noticed the @ in the files
ex.

- @package  CodeIgniter
- @author  EllisLab Dev Team
- @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc. (https://ellislab.com/)
- @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 - 2019, British Columbia Institute of Technology (https://bcit.ca/)
- @license https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT License
- @link    https://codeigniter.com
- @since   Version 1.0.0

What are those @ followed by the various names. I would like to know those so if by any chance I can use it in future.

Answer (score 1):

It can assist with your documentation.  For example, take a look at docBlock [dockblock](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/what-is-a-docblock.html).  It can scan your code for tags. Tags start with the @ sign.  There are 28 tags including @package, @author, @copyright, @license,  @link and since, which you have listed above.

Comment: oh okay. So it helps in documentation. Apart from that, does it serve anything in actual code or is it just only for documentation?

Comment: As far as I know, just auto-documentation.